# member function on Oracle object Error(17,5): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "AWARDSTAR" when expecting one of the following: if

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a member Function that will award a medal to a supervisor who supervises a certain number of employees and has certain years experience. however I keep getting the error mentioned in the title any help would be appreciated as I am kinda new to this.

HERE IS MY CREATE TYPE STATEMENT

```
create type employeeType under peopleType 
  (empID int,
   supervisorID ref employeeType,
   pos varchar2(20),
   salary number(8,2),
   bID ref branchType,
   joinDate date,
   member function awardStar(stars varchar2) return varchar2);
```

HERE IS MY CREATE TYPE-BODY STATEMENT

```
create or replace type body employeeType as
  member function awardStar(stars varchar2)
  return varchar2
  is 
    medal varchar2;  
    years number;
    emps number;
  begin
    select count (*)
    into   emps
    from   employee e
    where  Deref(e.supervisorID).empID = self.empID;

    years := trunc(months_between(sysDate,self.joinDate))/12;

    if years > 12 and emps > 6 then
      medal := 'Gold Medal';
    else if years > 6 and emps > 3 then
      medal := 'Silver Medal';
    else if years > 4 then
      medal := 'Brown Medal';
    end if;

    return medal;
  end awardStar;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you've used `else if` when you actually meant to use `elsif`. You need to either put in your `end if`s for each sub-if, or correct the typos.

I would suggest:

```
create or replace type body employeeType as
  member function awardStar(stars varchar2)
  return varchar2
  is 
    medal varchar2;  
    years number;
    emps number;
  begin
    select count(*)
    into   emps
    from   employee e
    where  Deref(e.supervisorID).empID = self.empID;

    years := trunc(months_between(sysDate,self.joinDate))/12;

    if years > 12 and emps > 6 then
      medal := 'Gold Medal';
    elsif years > 6 and emps > 3 then
      medal := 'Silver Medal';
    elsif years > 4 then
      medal := 'Brown Medal';
    end if;

    return medal;

    end awardStar;
end;
/
```

P.S. `Brown Medal`? Did you mean `Bronze Medal`?